# Activity Lifecycle - leaving onPause to be killed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an android APP where I defined some of activity methods (see example below).

Is there anyway to identify when the my APP leaves onPause method to be killed due to memory required from APP with higher priority? Tnx in advanced

```
public class Activity extends ApplicationContext {

 private static final String TAG = "TEST";
 private static final boolean D = true;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);    


 }

 public void onPause();

 super.onPause();
 if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");

 }


 public void onStop() {

 super.onStop();
 if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON STOP -");

 }


 public void onDestroy();


 super.onDestroy();
 if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON Destroy -");

 }


 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can override Activity.onLowMemory() method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onLowMemory()

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. On logCat I am getting the following message: **09-17 14:42:15.365: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(9301): Shutting down VM** Is there anyway to get this message based on activity methods?

Comment: Humm... maybe you can try to override Application.onLowMemory instead of Activity.onLowMemory(). Have you tried this?

Comment: yes, I have! But it didnt work! I found an APP sample from SDK folder - BluetoothChat -  that keeps alive the activity foreground loop for a long time. But it is not clear how it works that once there is not a service in running